# DocuSign envelope "sent" status not matching web application's status of "Delivery failure"

Tags: c#, docusignapi

When I retrieve an envelope from DocuSign via their API, the status of the envelope does not match DocuSign web application.

The status I'm getting back is "sent" - but on the web version, it's "delivery failure." I know there was a delivery failure as I entered an incorrect email address.

I've checked that the envelopeId match on the web version and the API.

Do I need to get the status from somewhere else?

I'm just retrieving the envelope using DocuSign's envelopeAPI.

```
public Envelope GetEnvelope(string envId) 
{
    EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
    Envelope envInfo = envelopesApi.GetEnvelope(this.AccountId, envId);
    return envInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an account level settings to send `Auto Responded` status via API or Connect. You need to contact your DocuSign Account Manager or DocuSign Support to enable below setting from DocuSign Internal Admin.

`Return Recipient Auto Responded Status in Connect/API`

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try to find out where I can set that.

Answer (score 0):

Try fetching the envelope's *recipient* status.

See [EnvelopeRecipients::list](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list)